# Removing the proxy and host from Netbeans

Tags: gradle, netbeans, proxy, libgdx, host

I know this questions is not related to programming but I can't find the root problem of my proxy/host.

Ok, let me explain, I am in China, so I have to make use of a VPN. The software is called SSTap and because of that reason I called the host in the same way.

For the project I am trying to make I am using LibGDX and gradle ofc.

After not being able to settle a proxy I removed it, as shown in the picture it is selected as "no proxy" and  there are no proxy settings, and down in the output I am getting the warning.

Is there another place to totally remove the host?

I am using "Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.3"

Thanks in advance I will write down more questions

ReEdit part:

Sorry I thought it was loaded

The warning is: **Warning: Failed to parse host SSTap**

The way I configure the host/proxy was in a pop-up window that have not appeared anymore and I am unable to find it after setting the host again, the only way that I know to see the host is by Tools -> Options -> General Tab, the picture is not complete but that is the path to get there

I am having difficulties to load the picture, I am in China and I am using a VPN, so it is quite hard to visualize it, since I created the account yesterday I am unable to post pictures and instead they are added by links automatically

[picture/warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfRMQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td3Kp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI24j.png)

Comment: [1] Although your question is not completely off topic because it relates to a Gradle project in NetBeans, I think you might have more luck with this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). [2] You state _"in the output I am getting the warning"_, but it is not clear what warning you are referring to. [3] Your question mentions _"as shown in the picture"_, but there is no picture.  [4] Your question would be improved by including some screen shot(s), and details of what you did to initially set the proxy.

Comment: Ive updated the photos @skomisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into my gradle.properties file found in C:\Users\User. gradle inside looks like this:

```
    ## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
    # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
    #
    # Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
    # The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
    # Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    # org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    #
    # When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
    # This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
    # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
    # org.gradle.parallel=true
    #Sat Dec 25 18:51:22 CST 2021 
systemProp.http.proxyHost=SSTap 
systemProp.https.proxyHost=SSTap 
systemProp.https.proxyPort=25378 
systemProp.http.proxyPort=25378 
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1
```

I removed the last 6 rows,created a new project using Desktop, Android, IOs, HTML in LibGDX , trusted all the projects with gradle, classes have no packages when created, if I create them or import them by myself (in desktop project). And even if it says "cannot find symbol"(class) within the core path e.g. **import com.pokedemon.game.Hello;**
the code runs

A problem that I had before when trying to resolve problems was: **com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.5.4**

Still no packages I closed Netbeans and open it again but again no packages **but the proxy and host are fixed now**