# Classes are being created without packages in Netbeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans, libgdx, package

everytime that I try to use LibGDX and netbeans I am struggling to just to get started.

[create class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWvab.png)

[class created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o82ks.png)

I am not sure if the photos are going to be visible since I just created my account and my reputation is low but let me explain myself in case they will not.

So I created another project using LibGDX this is the result I got:

> 

```
Executing 'C:\.....\ProTest/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon' To honour
> the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please
> consider using the daemon:
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html. Daemon
> will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
> > Task :android:clean UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :core:clean UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :desktop:clean UP-TO-DATE
> > Task :html:clean
> > Task :ios:clean UP-TO-DATE Warning: Failed to parse host SSTap Warning: Failed to parse host SSTap Deprecated Gradle features were
> used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use
> '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 21s 5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
> Done! To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing
> Gradle Project To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open ->
> build.gradle To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
```

After that I opened Netbeans and Opened the project, trustgradle execution...
And I opened core, desktop and IOs without any problem from the subprojects created.

I went to the desktop project and inside has a class called "DesktopLauncher"

the code inside is

```
> package com.supa.testa.desktop; import
> com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication; import
> com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration; public
> class DesktopLauncher {   public static void main (String[] arg) {
>       LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new
> LwjglApplicationConfiguration();      new LwjglApplication(new Testo (),
> config);  } }
```

and I created a class in the path "com.supa.testa" but it was created without mentioned the package on the top, I thought that by using extends Game will be fixed somehow as I cannot find the error and even write down the package path by myself... the code for the class "Testo" now looks like this:

```
package com.supa.testa;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
public class Testo extends Game{
    @Override
    public void create() {
    }
    
}
```

So I cameb back to the DesktopLauncher class and tried to create a class by using the "bulb" I dont know the name (help me with  that please) and another class with the same name "Testo" was created in another path but again without the package on the top and it implemented the ApplicaitonListener by itself

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
public class Testo implements ApplicationListener {
    public Testo() {
    }
    
}
```

then I came back to DesktopLauncher did the same and I could be doing that over and over again
it will go as "Testo_1" "Testo_2" and the class will never have a package and it will never be recognized

I tried to build and clean the project from the desktop, the core, the project itself, clean, build separately

Open and closed netbeans

create different projects (this was the last one)

The last thing I have tried, I pressed "Ctrl + Space bar" after the code:

```
new LwjglApplication(new .....
```

and the classes that appear are from other projects

When I created a project with LibGDX I am having this issue randomly

But now I can't get rid of it haha

I am not sure if its related with the Daemon

And in another of the tests I did the "LwjglApplicationConfiguration" library from badlogicgames seems like did not loaded because I was unable to use, did not appear at all, even after writing it manually it will not work (same as for the packages :(   )

Have a nice day :D

Reedit:

I tried to create another project the previous was using Desktop, Android, IOs and Html

I tried only with desktop and the packages are working properly

I tried with Desktop and Html and this is what I got

```
Generating app in C:......
Executing 'C:\........ setup\ProTestD__H/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProTestD__H'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download commons-logging-1.1.1.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
            > SSTap

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
```

After that I opened the project to try to:
**Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.**

In the Run gradle "--stacktrace":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i9q4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Cu3p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9ve0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e36Ez.png)

and the code still going Im not sure if the photos will be uploaded and it is a lot so I cannot copy paste it here, I will try to past what I think is important

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProTestD__H'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not download commons-logging-1.1.1.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1)
> > > Could not get resource 'ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
> > > Could not HEAD 'ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
> > > SSTap
>
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProTestD__H'.  at
>   org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
>
> Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could
> not download commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
> (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1)
>
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get
> resource
> 'ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
>
> Caused by:
> org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException:
> Could not HEAD
> 'ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
>
> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SSTap

Using "--info" got:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProTestD__H'.
>
> > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not download commons-logging-1.1.1.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1)
> > > Could not get resource 'ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
> > > Could not HEAD 'ttps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.
> > > SSTap
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Using "--scan" got this:

> .\gradlew.bat --configure-on-demand -w --scan -x check
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Auto-applied by using --scan
> - What went wrong: Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.4.1', artifact: 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.4.1']
>   was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.4.1')   Searched in the
>   following repositories:
>   Gradle Central Plugin Repository
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at ttps://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 2s

And i got this when trying to resolve and trust the project

```
SSTap<br/>Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.<br/>Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'.<br/>Could not download commons-logging-1.1.1.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1)<br/>Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.<br/>A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProTestD__H'.<br/>A problem occurred configuring root project 'ProTestD__H'.<br/>Could not run build action using connection to Gradle installation 'C:\......\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7.1-bin\bwlcbys1h7rz3272sye1xwiv6\gradle-6.7.1'.
```

I also tried to follow the tutorials in [LibGDX tutorials](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/libgdx/) [LibGDX tutorials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWvab.png)
When trying to run the project in android by using the desktop folder
I got the "Warning: Class 'com.my.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher' not found in module 'Test'" I applied, tried to run and got:
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip'.

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.13'
        classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.12'
        

    } }

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Kiya"
        gdxVersion = '1.10.0'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.12'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.3'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    } }

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        
    } }

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        
    } }

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        
    } }

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: "org.gretty"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        
    } }

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but if your problem is, that the `DesctopLauncher` doesn't know the class `Testo` you just need to **import it**: `import com.supa.testa.Testo`

Also you should place your Game classes (and packages) like Testo in the core project, since it will be used in all projects (desctop and ios).

You should have a look at the [libGDX tutorials](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/libgdx/).
Especially [Setup](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/libgdx/setup) and [Hello World](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/libgdx/hello-world) should contain what you are searching for.

Comment: I also tried it, but that does not work, and I know I should write it on core but if I do so, I cannot run the project.

Comment: As far as I know if I create a class in core, it should be created in project: desktop, android, html and IOs, but it does not. I tried to crete the packages by myself and also tried to import them by myself but that does not work I can create the same class within the same project but not within the same package but I still cannot call the class in another class

Comment: If you create a class in the core project, all the other projects can use it, but there will not be any copies of the classes in all projects. There seems to be a problem in your build.gradle file, which causes the build to fail. Can you update your question and add the content of the build.gradle? (the one in the root folder, where desktop, android and html folders are placed)

Comment: Ive added the build.gradle

Comment: The build.gradle file seems to be ok to me. The apache commons-logging-1.1.1.jar that fails is probably just the first transitive dependency that is pulled. This might be a general problem with your gradle. I don't realy know what could cause this. Maybe that would be worth a new question...

Comment: I have this other post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624157/removing-the-proxy-and-host-from-netbeans/70679316#70679316

Answer (score 0):

I have this other post... [Removing the proxy and host from Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624157/removing-the-proxy-and-host-from-netbeans/70679316#70679316) I just fixed it.... and even tho the packages are stillnot visible in core or desktop project, if I create a class in core and put some code in it and run it from Desktoplauncher it works even tho it shows an error **cannot find symbol**(class), but the projects runs perfectly...  for now O_O

The classes are still created without package and if the package is created(typed) by myself it shows error but now it works. Even if it is a project that uses ScreenAdapter

This is what I did....

I went into my gradle.properties file found in C:\Users\User. gradle inside looks like this:

```
    ## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
    # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
    #
    # Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
    # The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
    # Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    # org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    #
    # When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
    # This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
    # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
    # org.gradle.parallel=true
    #Sat Dec 25 18:51:22 CST 2021 
systemProp.http.proxyHost=SSTap 
systemProp.https.proxyHost=SSTap 
systemProp.https.proxyPort=25378 
systemProp.http.proxyPort=25378 
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1
```

I removed the last 6 rows,created a new project using Desktop, Android, IOs, HTML in LibGDX , trusted all the projects with gradle, classes have no packages when created, if I create them or import them by myself (in desktop project). And even if it says "cannot find symbol"(class) within the core path e.g. import com.pokedemon.game.Hello; the code runs